# Unable to Start-Process using another AD account?

Tags: powershell

The below script is unable to start the application as Separate AD user account.

I wanted the run the below application in **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools** as separate AD account **DOMAIN\Admin.User1** as oppose to just double clicking it and run as *DOMAIN\FirstName.LastName* normal user.

[image]

This is the script i have created but failed to open:

```
$ApplicationList = @(
    '%windir%\system32\dsac.exe'
    '%windir%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s'
    '%windir%\system32\mmc.exe %windir%\system32\Cluadmin.msc'
    '%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\dnsmgmt.msc'
)
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Use your Admin Account" -Title "Run as other account script"
ForEach ( $Application in $ApplicationList ) {
    Start-Process -FilePath $Application -Credential $credential
}
```

I also have checked the **DOMAIN\Admin.User1** Account is not even locked, however, the issue is like:

```
Start-Process:
Line |
  11 |      Start-Process -FilePath $Application -Credential $credential
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | This command cannot be run due to the error: The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.
```

The below line works, but not sure how to integrate it to the above main script as above:

```
Start-Process "$($env:windir)\system32\compmgmt.msc" -ArgumentList "/s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command below,

`Start-Process "$($env:windir)\system32\compmgmt.msc" -ArgumentList "/s"`

worked with the `-ArgumentList` parameter you have said, so replace this in the `$ApplicationList` to run with `Start-Process`, for example for `compmgmt.exe` only
You would change the `$applicationList`

```
$ApplicationList = @(
    '"$($env:windir)\system32\compmgmt.msc" -ArgumentList "/s"'
)
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Use your Admin Account" -Title "Run as other account script"
ForEach ( $Application in $ApplicationList ) {
    Start-Process $Application
}
```